# css is not working correctly in chrome

Tags: html, css

hello everyone I am getting one problem related to designing issue. This is my website :

[www.spin69.com](http://www.spin69.com)

Now problem is this that my desgin is working well in firefox. But in chrome its design is not working properly. When I check its css from firebug. It cannot show me my css but its show me reset css please check it on chrome and firefox and tell me what is wrong in this website
I am a developer and I have only basic knowledge of css so please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: CSS clearly **is** working. Can you be more specific?

Comment: OP asked to check both in FF browser and Chrome browser. The allignment seems to be disturbed in Chrome

Comment: so what i have to do @VamsiKrishna

Comment: Simply remove `reset.css`.

Answer (score 0):

In the css of header>nav>ul class="menu">li

Change the menu li element padding from 2px to 1px.

```
#menu > li {
background: url("../images/menu_line.png") no-repeat scroll right 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
float: left;
padding-right: 1px;
```

}

That should work in both the browsers.